# When given a list, how to check if elements are equal, or not

Tags: java

Say, you're given a `List<KVPair>`, where each `KVPair` has a `String key`, `String Value` and `.equals()` method that does things right.

**How would you confirm that each of the elements in the list is like the other, or see if at least one is not?**

In other words, if we have

```
KVPair kvp1 = new KVPAir("key", "value");
KVPair kvp2 = new KVPAir("key", "value");

List<KVPair> l = new ArrayList<KVPair>();
l.add(kvp1);
l.add(kvp2);
```

The one approach i can think of is, sort the list first and iterate until next is not like previous.

Is there a simpler, cleaner way to find the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a generic solution:

**Don't forget to do the empty check.** First time you add element to the set, it will always be added

```
public static boolean isListOfSameElements(List<? extends Object> l) {
    Set<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>(l.size());
    for (Object o : l) {
        if (set.isEmpty()) {
            set.add(o);
        } else {
            if (set.add(o)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If hashCode() is also implemented properly, you can add them all into a HashSet and see if you get duplicates:

```
 Set<KVPair> set = new HashSet<KVPair>(l.size());
 for (KVPair p: l){
   if (!set.add(p))
      // you have a duplicate
 }
```

or even (a bit wasteful)

```
Set<KVPair> set = new HashSet<KVPair)(l);
if (l.size() != set.size())
   // you have a duplicate
if (set.size() < 2)
   // all elements are equal
```

Answer (score 1):

Using java streams:

```
list.stream().distinct().count() == 1
```